# how reference member comment in Sandcastle

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, sandcastle

Code sample :

```
//<remarks>
// look <see cref="Class2.DoSomething(object)"  />
//</remarks>
public class Class1 {
}

public class Class2 {
  //<summary>do something ...<summary>
  public void DoSomething(object obj) { ... }
}
```

I need `Class1` "remarks" content contain the "summary" of `Class2.DoSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [include tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx) to put the common documentation in a separate file.